# Trouble using UpdateCursor when setting the value

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis, esri

Using ArcDesktop 10.1 & Python 2.7:
I am working on a code that searches for values within 13 fields and, based on what it finds within those 13 fields, it concatenates a string and puts the result in an existing (empty) field.

It uses a search cursor to search the 13 fields.  Then uses the result of that in an update cursor to concatenate the string.

I am having trouble getting the result into the field using the setValue - Line 40 of the code below @ urow.setValue(commentsField, easementType).  The error message is very unhelpful (RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.)

I am not sure how to correctly get the value set in the field desired.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import arcpy, os, math
from itertools import izip
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\mdelgado\\Desktop\\WorkinDog.gdb"

#These are my variables
fc = "EASEMENTS"
commentsField = "Comments"
typeFields = ["ABANDONED", "ACCESS", "AERIAL", "BLANKET", "COMM", "DRAIN", "ELEC", "GEN_UTIL", "LANDSCAPE", "PARKING", "PIPELINE", "SAN_SEWR", "SIDEWALK", "SPECIAL", "STM_SEWR", "WATER"]
fieldNames = ["ABANDONED", "ACCESS", "AERIAL", "BLANKET", "COMMUNICATION", "DRAINAGE", "ELECTRIC", "GENERAL UTILITY", "LANDSCAPE", "PARKING", "PIPELINE", "SANITATION SEWER", "SIDEWALK", "SPECIAL", "STORM SEWER", "WATER"]
fieldValues = []
easementType = ""

#This is my search cursor
scursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
srow = scursor.next()
for field in typeFields:
    srowValue = (srow.getValue(field))
    fieldValues.append(srowValue)
    srow = scursor.next()
print fieldValues

#This is my update cursor
ucursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for urow in ucursor:

    #This is where I begin the loop to concatenate the comment field
    for (value, name) in izip(fieldValues, fieldNames):
        print str(value) + " " + name

        #This is where I check each field to find out which types the easement is
        if value == 1:
            easementType = easementType + name + ", "

    #This is where I format the final concatenated string
    easementType = easementType[:-2]
    print easementType

    #This is where the field is updated with the final string using the cursor
    urow.setValue(commentsField, easementType)
    ucursor.updateRow(urow)
    urow = cursor.next()

del urow
del ucursor
del srow
del scursor
```

Comment: Does it execute correctly for some rows and then break? Have you checked that the length of the `Comments` field is enough to accommodate the longest possible concatenated `easementType`?

Comment: Great suggestion!  When looking into this I discovered I was referencing a field alias and not the actual field name.  That solved one problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uninformative 999999 error is one of the worst.

I suggest a couple modifications to your approach that may make it simpler to troubleshoot. First, [use the da Cursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/data-access-using-cursors.htm) -- they are faster, and the syntax is a little simpler.

Second, you don't need a separate Search and Update -- the Update can "search" other fields in the same row in addition to updating fields. (The current code, assuming it was working correctly, would be putting the same `fieldValues` into every row the UpdateCursor affected.)

```
fieldNames = ["ABANDONED", "ACCESS", "AERIAL", "BLANKET", "COMMUNICATION", "DRAINAGE",
              "ELECTRIC", "GENERAL UTILITY", "LANDSCAPE", "PARKING", "PIPELINE", "SANITATION SEWER",
              "SIDEWALK", "SPECIAL", "STORM SEWER", "WATER"]
cursorFields = ["ABANDONED", "ACCESS", "AERIAL", "BLANKET", "COMM", "DRAIN", 
                "ELEC", "GEN_UTIL", "LANDSCAPE", "PARKING", "PIPELINE", "SAN_SEWR",
                "SIDEWALK", "SPECIAL", "STM_SEWR", "WATER", "Comments"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, cursorFields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        easementType = ""
        for x in range(13):
            if row[x] == 1:
                easementType += fieldNames[x] + ", "
        easementType = easementType[:-2]
        print easementType

        row[13] = easementType
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: These modifications are brilliant!  They solved all of my issues.  The script is running perfectly now.  I can't thank you enough for your advice!